# Counting number of documents

Tags: python, path, count, operating-system

I have a corpus, and I need to count the number of documents and tokens in the corpus as a whole, but also its subparts.

The code I have been developing so far looks like this:

```
def gather_data(path):
    words = 0
    articles = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            if not f.endswith('_metadata.txt') and f.endswith('.txt'):
                articles += 1
                p = os.path.join(root, f)
                with open(p) as duo_file:
                        for line in duo_file.readlines():
                            words += len(line.split())
    write_to_data(words, articles, current_path)
```

The counting is pretty crude, I know, need to develop that further. However, what I can't seem to figure out is how to count a total (entire corpus), and count each sup-part of corpus. So the structure is, Entire Corpus - (Part 1, Part 2, Part 3) - and then each part has sub-parts as well, so we have Part 1 - (part 1, part 2, part 3).

So in essence its a list of lists:

```
[Corpus, [Part 1[part 1, part 2]], [Part 3 [...]]...]]
```

So I would like the counts to be (from the above example)

```
Corpus -> counts
Part 1 -> counts
Part 1.part 1 -> counts
Part 1.part 2 -> counts
```

Someone asked what the parts are. They are folders. So, the main folder is called corpus, that folder consists of several folders, each a sup-part of the corpus, and those folders consists of more folders or files. Its a directory of folder - folders - (folders or files)

So basically I want to count all the files that are below each folder. So I want a count for the root folder, which means counting everything, then a count for each folder below root, then counts (if there are more folders) for those folders.

And I want it to be printed out like:

Corpus: x articles, x words
Faculty of Natural Sciences: x articles, x words
Institute of physics: x articles, x words

So Faculty of Natural Sciences is a subcorpus of Corpus, and Institute of physics is a subcorpus of Faculty of Natural Sciences. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: What is part 1, 2 and 3? what is the criteria to divide a file to parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When given the keyword argument `topdown=False`, `os.walk` will generate the subdirectories of a directory before it generates the directory. In other words, it's like a postorder tree search. We can use this to do a recursive count of the number of entries in each part of the corpus.

Suppose our directory structure is like this:

```
./corpus
├── part_1
│   ├── sub_1
│   │   ├── 1
│   │   ├── 2
│   │   └── 3
│   └── sub_2
│       ├── 1
│       └── 2
└── part_2
    └── part_1
        ├── 1
        ├── 2
        └── 3
```

We can get a count of the entries in each subdirectory by doing a bottom-up walk and summing the sizes of the subdirectories:

```
counts = {}
for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk("./corpus", topdown=False):
    counts[dirpath] = len(fnames)
    for d in dirnames:
        key = os.path.join(dirpath, d)
        counts[dirpath] += counts[key]
```

A test:

```
>>> counts
{'./corpus': 8,
 './corpus/part_1': 5,
 './corpus/part_1/sub_1': 3,
 './corpus/part_1/sub_2': 2,
 './corpus/part_2': 3,
 './corpus/part_2/part_1': 3}
```